# How to Deserialize xml in c#?

Tags: c#, xml

How to Deserialize below xml return to variable in c#?

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?>
<alipay>
    <is_success>T</is_success>
    <request>
        <param name="_input_charset">UTF-8</param>
        <param name="currency">USD</param>
        <param name="buyer_identity_code">2013112012345678</param>
        <param name="identity_code_type">qrcode</param>
        <param name="mcc">4021</param>
        <param name="extend_info">{"licence":"123",name=”LG”}</param>
        <param name="partner_trans_id">2010121000000002</param>
        <param name="partner">2088102012343978</param>
        <param name="password">SJV88po0XvIptqWGM4rxP5EQ</param>
        <param name="memo">shopping</param>
        <param name="service">alipay.acquire.overseas.pay</param>
        <param name="sign">22904adafb1806178b410d2d5c9c02a3</param>
        <param name="sign_type">MD5</param>
        <param name=“trans_name”>Belkin wrist type</param>
        <param name="trans_amount">39.25</param>
        <param name="trans_create_time">20131120153059</param>
    </request>
    <response>
        <alipay>
            <alipay_trans_id>2011091703338463</alipay_trans_id>
            <partner_trans_id>201311221000000002</partner_trans_id>
            <alipay_buyer_login_id>cao***@126.com</alipay_buyer_login_id>
            <alipay_buyer_user_id>2088102130896433</alipay_buyer_user_id>
            <alipay_pay_time>20131120155823</alipay_pay_time>
            <exchange_rate>6.0939</exchange_rate>
            <trans_amount>39.25</trans_amount>
            <trans_amount_CNY>239.19</trans_amount_CNY>
            <result_code>SUCCESS</result_code>
        </alipay>
    </response>
    <sign>6fb8a322f15cfd0fcfe65301b10f6994</sign>
    <sign_type>MD5</sign_type>
</alipay>
```

Comment: (1) Copy XML into clipboard (excluding the first line `<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?>`), (2) In Visual Studio select `Edit | Paste Special | Paste XML as Classes`. (3) Profit!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Deserialize XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

Comment: You can get model of `xml` data from https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ then with `XmlSerializer` convert it to object.

Comment: @AndyRefuerzo Different is <param name="_input_charset">

Comment: Still an XML Document.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's a good idea to check out [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you get a class for this xml you can use [this tool](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) or using [this visual studio functionality](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/ahmed-anwar's-blog/2014/07/10/converting-xml-to-c-classes-in-one-click)

Also this xml will not parse, you are using strange apostrophes in the trans_name line

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication62
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var results = doc.Descendants("response").FirstOrDefault().Elements("alipay").Select(x => new
            {
                alipay_trans_id = (string)x.Element("alipay_trans_id"),
                partner_trans_id = (string)x.Element("partner_trans_id"),
                alipay_buyer_login_id = (string)x.Element("alipay_buyer_login_id"),
                alipay_buyer_user_id = (string)x.Element("alipay_buyer_user_id"),
                alipay_pay_time = (string)x.Element("alipay_pay_time"),
                exchange_rate = (decimal)x.Element("exchange_rate"),
                trans_amount = (decimal)x.Element("trans_amount"),
                trans_amopunt_CNY = (decimal)x.Element("alipay_trans_id"),
                result_code = (string)x.Element("result_code")
            }).FirstOrDefault();

        }
    }
}
```